# page on github pages can't display local image and font

Tags: tailwind-css, github-pages

help
i haven't found the right solution for this problem, i added ./ to the url can solve the problem, but on the other side in tailwind there are arbitrary values ​​bg-[url('/dist/img/bg.jpg')] i can't add class with a dot in it. and also on local font @fontface which is in input.css i have added ./ but still not working the font on github pages...
https://github.com/nurulasrulroji-ajeye/portfolio-tailwind-css